# React-Redux action - Expected `onClick` listener to be a function instead got a value of `object` type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having difficulty properly calling the "logout" action within my navbar component. The action is there to reset the state; however, when I try to call it as shown in the following code, it is not a function, but rather the object that is returned. I have even tried calling it with an arrow function within the onClick property, but I get the same error message.

Navbar.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { logout } from '../../actions/auth';

const Navbar = ({ auth: { isAuthenticated, loading } }, logout) => {
  const authLinks = (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a onClick={logout} href='#!'>
          <i className='fas fa-sign-out-alt'></i>{' '}
          <span className='hide-sm'>Logout</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );

  const guestLinks = (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to='/#!'>Developers</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );

  return (
    <nav className='navbar bg-dark'>
      <h1>
        <Link to='/'>
          <i className='fas fa-code'></i> DevConnector
        </Link>
      </h1>
      {!loading && (
        <Fragment>{isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}</Fragment>
      )}
    </nav>
  );
};

Navbar.propTypes = {
  logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(Navbar);
```

I am calling the following action...

```
export const logout = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGOUT });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logout` is a prop. Props are passed as inside an object which is the first argument of a function component. There's a misplaced `}`, which makes `logout` the *second* argument.

```
const Navbar = ({ auth: { isAuthenticated, loading } }, logout) => {
                                                     ^^
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
const Navbar = ({ auth: { isAuthenticated, loading }, logout }) => {
```

Comment: Oh crap! It seems its always the simplest things that I overlook. Thanks a ton!